# Angular 5 - How to get a variable from HTML to component

Tags: angular, angular5

I have table containing two columns in HTML:

```
            <table class="table">
              <tr>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Total des messages</th>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngFor="let ac of accounts;">
                <td>{{ac}}</td>
                <td>{{totalFdAc}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

First column is an array of strings and looped by each elements while the second one is the result of called function where the value of first column is set as argument.

Here is the sample of component.ts:

```
//Get total feedback by Customer
this.accountService.countFeedbacksByAcc(ac).subscribe(res => {
        this.totalFdAc = res;
        console.log(res);
      }, err => {
      console.log(err);
});
```

How to make it possible ?

Comment: Please can you explain a bit better what do you want to do? Everything is a little confusing. Which variable do you want to get?

Comment: I want to get element of accounts in html which means {{ac}} and put it in function countFeedbacksByAcc(ac).. Is there a way to make it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over an array returned by a function resolver pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503311/looping-over-an-array-returned-by-a-function-resolver-pipe)

Comment: As we can call `countFeedbacksByAcc  | apply : ac `

Comment: @Atom, Why not use forkJoin to get all the response and show in .html? it's some like : forkJoin(account.map(a=>this.accountService.countFeedbacksByAcc(a.ac)).subscribe(res=>(console.log(res)})

Comment: @Buggy, calling function in template is not working + return error : Parser Error: Unexpected token | at column 39 in [let ac of accounts;countFeedbacksByAcc | apply : ac]

Comment: It must work, could you please provide live example(stackblitz) ?