# Looping over an array returned by an imported function?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

We have the `async` pipe to resolve `Observables` within template `*ngFor` expressions.  Is there a pipe that can resolve / call a function that returns an array to be looped over.

For example if we have something like this:

```
  <app-todo *ngFor="let todo of todosFunction | call"
```

Then angular would use the call pipe to resolve the `todosFunction` into the array of todos it returns.

### Use Case

```
export enum VISIBILITY_FILTER {
  SHOW_COMPLETED = 'Completed',
  SHOW_ACTIVE = 'Active',
  SHOW_ALL = 'All'
}

export function VISIBILITY_FILTER_VALUES():string[] {
  return Object.keys(VISIBILITY_FILTER).map(k => VISIBILITY_FILTER[k]);
}
```

I'd like to be able to loop over the `VISIBILITY_FILTER_VALUES` directly simply y importing and using it (without declaring it as a property on the component).  Is this possible?

Or perhaps it's possible to create a pipe that processes the enum FILTER_VALUES directory and creates the array out of it?

Comment: There is no such pipe by default, probably because it is not recommended to invoke functions from the template. You better refactor code and prepare data in your controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do

`<app-todo *ngFor="let todo of todosFunction()">` and define `todosFunction()`, which returns an array, in your `ts` file.

Comment: Calling methods from the template is discouraged in Angular because your method will be called on every change detection cycle and angular runs x2 cycles in dev-mode

Comment: @Vikas TIL. Thanks! Save the array into a variable, and call the variable.

Comment: I added the use case I was trying out to the question.  The array will be the same on each call, so I was hoping I could import it and use it directly in the template without declaring the property referencing the array on the component.  Any thoughts on whether this is possible?

Comment: Sounds like it's a good idea to declare in the component. Can you tell us why you would like to *not* do that?

Comment: It's shorter to just import it and use it in the template directly.  The values are always static and derived from the enum (See updated question) so I'm trying to minimize the boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any built in ones but writing one is pretty simple:

> Pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'call'
})
export class CallPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(typeof value === 'function') {
      return value(args);
    }
  }

}
```

> Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
 data(times) {
    return [1, 2, 3].map(x => x*times);
  }
}
```

> Component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let i of data | call: 3">{{i}}</p>
```

This is a list of [built-in pipes](https://angular.io/api?type=pipe) if you wonder.

Comment: Thanks Nima and @Buggy.  I tried it out on the import standalone, however that did not work.  Do you know if it's possible to create a pipe or some other mechanism that could work on the imported FILTER_VALUES enum type directly?  I guess I could also simply export the values array instead of a function, but I don't think Angular knows how to process imports that are not declared in component state ...

Comment: @Ole There isn't anyway to use static methods or imported classes or cnums directly inside template, you need to put them inside of a parameter in class first then use them as far as I know. Something like `public x = VISIBILTY_FILTER;` and then using x inside your template.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the function like this? , there is no need of another pipe to do the same.

```
 <app-todo *ngFor="let todo of todosFunction()">
```

however it is recommended to prepare your array inside the component and bind it to variable instead of calling a function.

Comment: OK Cool - I tried it at first with import {VISIBILITY_FILTER, VISIBILITY_FILTER_VALUES } and then calling VISIBILITY_FILTER_VALUES() within the loop template, but it did not resolve.  If I add a variable to the class like filters = VISIBILITY_FILTER_VALUES, and call filters() in the loop it works.  So I assume that the function cannot be an imported function but must be a property on the component class?

Comment: Why is it recommended and by whom?

Comment: Recommended by angular team itself , because the function gets called in each digest cycle

Comment: @Vikas thats what i mentioned above

Comment: @Sajeetharan my Bad I was commenting on the accepted answer :/

Answer (score 1):

Call function in template is really bad as function will be executed on each Change Detection cycle.

Pipe in other hand is pure (by default) so it will be called only when input parameters was changed.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'apply',
})
export class ApplyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T, U extends any[]>(fn: (...fnArgs: U) => T, ...args: U): T {
    return fn(...args);
  }
}
```